# Headcount in Each Hour of the Operation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get an headcount of the amount of employees I have per hour. The earliest shift starts at 03:00 and the latest shift end at 06:00 (the next day). The formula that I am using is returning a correct headcount from hours 03:00-23:00. But from 23:00-07:00 (next day) the headcount is off. The formula I am using for 23:00-00:00 is:

```
=COUNTIFS('May 2-May 8'!$D:$D, ">"&AC$30, 'May 2-May 8'!$C:$C,"<"&AD$30, 'May 2-May 8'!$H:$H, "SKD", 'May 2-May 8'!$I:$I, "CREW CHIEF") + COUNTIFS('May 2-May 8'!$D:$D, "<="&$I$30, 'May 2-May 8'!$C:$C,"<"&AC$30, 'May 2-May 8'!$H:$H, "SKD", 'May 2-May 8'!$I:$I, "CREW CHIEF").
```

The formula I am using for 00:00-07:00 is:

```
 =COUNTIFS('May 2-May 8'!$D:$D, "<="&$L$30, 'May 2-May 8'!$C:$C,">="&V$30, 'May 2-May 8'!$H:$H, "SKD", 'May 2-May 8'!$I:$I, "CREW CHIEF").
```

[image: May 2-May 8]

[image: Graph]

I tried so many ways to figure this out myself, but for some reason I cannot get it.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you post your data as a screenshot? It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet for troubleshooting possible solutions. Having to manually enter the data is discouraging to many who might otherwise assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I’m new to stack overflow, so I wasn’t sure what the best approach was.

Comment: I think it is OK, maybe even preferable, to post a screenshot of desired **results**, but an example of the original data is much easier to use when posted as a textual data table.  And if it's easier to use, you'll attract more help. Somewhere on the forum is a frequently referenced thread on the topic, but I don't have that reference handy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to simplify your dataset in order to avoid performing complex formula.
the problem you have its very easy to solve.

you need to add two additional columns for the shift start and shift end or you can edit your existing columns. instead of time format you should put date and time format. then its very easy.

=COUNTIFS(Table1[SHIFT_START_DATETIME],"<="&$K$1+J5,Table1[SHIFT_END_DATETIME],">="&$K$1+J5)

[image: Example]

Comment: if you can't change the original table you could use `=COUNTIFS(Table1[Date] + Table1[SHIFT_START],"<="&$K$1+J5,Table1[Date] + Table1[SHIFT_END] + if (Table1[SHIFT_END] < Table1[SHIFT_START],1,0),">="&$K$1+J5)` assuming @Saif's solution (assuming date is stored as a date and the times are stored as times)